# how to awk values of perl array?

Tags: perl, perlscript

I have an some attributes with values stored in an array as below, now i need to perform some checks on attribute values,Suggest me how can i proceed in perl.

> @arr1 = `cat passwd.txt|tr ' ' '\n'|egrep -i "maxage|minage"|sort'`;

array arr1 contains info as "maxage=0  minage=0"

In this i need to perform **if condition** on the value of maxage, is there any way like below, suggest me as i am new to perl.

`if ( @arr1[0]|awk -F= '{print $2}' == 0 )
  {
      printf  "Then print task done";
  }`

Comment: Can you give us some _example_ data. Because this is a really bad way of doing it, when you can just use perl to do the whole thing.

Comment: Please show the `passwd.txt` file.

Comment: passwd.txt file has the output info of `#lsuser root` in aix operating system. I just taken into a file for experimenting on it, actually i need to use that command.

Comment: Ok..Show the output anyway since it will help us create a solution for you.

Comment: passwd.txt data is :
root id=0 pgrp=system minage=0 maxage=0 maxexpired=-1 minalpha=1 minother=1 mindiff=4 maxrepeats=8 minlen=8 histexpire=0

Answer (score 1):

You can do the whole process in Perl. For example:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my $fn = 'passwd.txt';
open ( my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";
my @arr1 = sort grep /maxage|minage/i, split ' ', <$fh>;
close $fh;
if ( (split /=/, shift @arr1)[1] == 0) {
   say "done";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
@arr1 = `cat passwd.txt | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -i "maxage|minage"| sort`;
$x = `$arr1[0] |  awk -F= {print $2}`; // maybe $3 is true index
if ( x == 0 )
  {
      print  "Then print task done";
  }
```